# comparing a new version of a data frame to identify changes into a new data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3], 'ETD': ['06.02.2021', '05.01.2021', '07.02.2021'], 'ETA':['06.02.2021', '05.01.2021', '07.02.2021']}, 
                  columns=['ID', 'ETD', 'ETA'])

    ID  ETD         ETA
0   1   06.02.2021  06.02.2021
1   2   05.01.2021  05.01.2021
2   3   07.02.2021  07.02.2021



df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3], 'ETD': ['07.02.2021', '05.01.2021', '07.02.2021'], 'ETA':['06.02.2021', '05.01.2021', '04.02.2021']}, 
                  columns=['ID', 'ETD', 'ETA'])

    ID  ETD         ETA
0   1   07.02.2021  06.02.2021
1   2   05.01.2021  05.01.2021
2   3   07.02.2021  04.02.2021
```

The two Dfs have same columns, but they are can be of different lengths. Based on the ID key, i'd like to come compare the ETA and ETD dates and where there is a difference, the Row must be copied

to a new dataframe otherwise pass.

desired DF:

```
df_CNG = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 3], 'ETA-last': ['06.02.2021', '07.02.2021'],'ETD-last': ['    06.02.2021', '07.02.2021'],'ETD-new': ['07.02.2021', '07.02.2021'], 'ETA-new':['06.02.2021', '04.02.2021']}, 
                  columns=['ID', 'ETA-last', 'ETD-new', 'ETA-last', 'ETA-new'])

    ID  ETA-last    ETD-new     ETA-last    ETA-new
0   1   06.02.2021  07.02.2021  06.02.2021  06.02.2021
1   3   07.02.2021  07.02.2021  07.02.2021  04.02.2021
```

As a solution, i've tried doing a while loop going line by line and comparing dates and copying cells to the df_CNG, but this is slow and also, the page on jupyter notebook becomes unresponsive and takes too long to load. is there a better way?

```
e = 0
Rows_e = len(df2)
while True:
    print(e)
    if e == Rows_e:
        break
    else:
        l = 0
        Rows_l = len(df)
        while True:
            print(l)
            if l == (Rows_l+1):
                break
            else:
                if (df2.loc[e,'ID'] == df.loc[l,'ID']):
                    
                    if df2.loc[e,'ETD'] == df.loc[l,'ETD'] and df2.loc[e,'ETA'] == df.loc[l,'ETA']:
                        e+=1
                        break
                       
                    elif df2.loc[e,'ETD'] != df.loc[l,'ETD'] or df2.loc[e,'ETA'] != df.loc[l,'ETA']:
                        df_CNG.loc[e,'ETD-new'] = df2.loc[e,'ETD']
                        df_CNG.loc[e,'ETD-last'] = df.loc[l,'ETD']
                        
                        df_CNG.loc[e,'ETA-new'] = df2.loc[e,'ETA']
                        df_CNG.loc[e,'ETA-last'] = df.loc[l,'ETA']
                        
                        df_CNG.loc[e,'ID'] = df2.loc[e,'ID']
                        
                            
                        e+=1
                        break
                        
                    
                    else: 
                        e+=1
                        break
                else:
                    l+=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try  merging both df's on ID and then make ID as index:

```
out=df.merge(df2,on='ID',how='inner',suffixes=('-last','-new'))
#(If you need outer merge then instead of 'inner' write how='outer' in the above code)
```

then:

```
m=(out['ETA-new'].eq(out['ETA-last'])) & (out['ETD-new'].eq(out['ETD-last']))
#check if values are equal or not
out=out[~m]
#Filter out result
```

output of `out`:

```
    ID  ETD-last    ETA-last    ETD-new     ETA-new
0   1   06.02.2021  06.02.2021  07.02.2021  06.02.2021
1   3   07.02.2021  07.02.2021  07.02.2021  04.02.2021
```